# c# how to disable other form's button?

Tags: c#

i have 2 forms 
1st is login
2nd is main

what i want is login page has 2 buttons user login(i'm done with coding for this) and guest login

But in guest login i want to disable a button in main form. 
How can i do this?

i tried this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqjUaE3EbcY

use `Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Owner = this;` in form 1
and `(this.Owner as Form1).button3.Enabled = false;` in form2

but got "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" in line that i set button.Enabled = false

Comment: Nobody is going to watch tutorial on YT to see how your code looks like. Please, provide [mcve].

Comment: okok my bad i already added my code

Comment: Use properties, when a user clicks anything, update them, simple as that

Answer (score 0):

In your main form, in form's cunstructor:

```
public Form1()
{

}
```

change it to accept a parameter like:

```
public Form1(bool isGuest)
{
     if(isGuest) button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Then in your login form, open you new form with the parameter you want:

for guest:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1(true);
frm.Show();
```